# Unable to access WordPress database with MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, connection, mysql-workbench

So I've been told that the connection properties I need to access the WP database are in wp-config.php in the root of my WordPress directory. I found this file and found these values:

```
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '??????????');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '**********');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', '++++++++++');
```

Obviously I starred out the real values, but suffice it to say I tried to log into this database with MySQL Workbench with:

```
Hostname: ++++++++++
Username: ??????????
Password: **********
Port: 3306
```

I keep getting an "Unknown MySQL server host" when I try to connect. My WordPress site seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that MySQL Workbench apparently required the "Database Management IP Address" rather than the DB Hostname.

Comment: MySQL Workbench uses the same name resolution process as any other network based application. However not all names can be resolved from everywhere, especially those that are assigned in a private network. The php scripts run on the remote server and have other access possibilities than your local MySQL Workbench instance.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Check MySQL Services is running ?

**Run** -> **services.msc** -> check if not then **manually start**.
If you use WAMP Server then you forgot to start WAMP Server.

### Solution 2

you can not set instance (local user)

1. MySQL Workbench
2. Mange Server Instances (bottom right corner)
3. Connection box
4. select `Local Instance ($ServerName) - root@127.0.0.1:3306 '<'Standard(TCP/IP)>`
5. Edit Selected
6. under Parameters, Hostname change localhost or 127.0.0.1
7. click Test Connection

### Solution 3

Find this problem is connection problem or Workbench problem.

1. Open a command prompt got to mysql bin directory path
2. Type `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306`
3. Try to check you connect successfully or not.

Comment: So I tried pinging the host and got:

Ping request could not find host ++++++++++

This is almost certainly the problem right? Why would that hostname be incorrect inside wp-config.php

Comment: There are no "Mange Server Instances"! Only "Mange Server Connections" and "models"... Please show how to do in 2017...